# How to call a function from class when clicking on PHP Button?

Tags: javascript, php, function, class

friends.

I have a PHP Class like this:

```
class DiffFunctions {
    function showMessage($msg){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg')</script>";
    }
}
```

and I have tried this code in PHP Page:

```
<?php
include_once './Classes/DiffFunctions.php';
$myFuns2 = new DiffFunctions();
?>
<button id="sendMsg" type="submit" onclick="$myFuns2->showMessage('You have clicked the button')">Click Here To Show The Message</button>
```

But It did not work!

Comment: You're combining server side programming with client side programming, it doesn't work like that. Instead, use a form and  `if (isset($_POST['button']))` to then run the method.

Comment: $myFuns2->showMessage('You have clicked the button')">Click Here To Show The Message is php code running on the server and it should be inside `<?php ?>` tags. `onclick=""` requires javascript code running in the browser, not `php` code.

Comment: PaulH, the button code is in html form code

Comment: Jamie Bicknell, How can I do it?

Comment: I want to run a php function on clicking on button, how can I do it?